# RESTful Webservice GET file

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a RESTful service implemented in java to upload files. Here is the code:

```
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
public String uploadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {

    String resultStatus = "fileupload error";
    String fileRepository = "/MobilityPatterns/";

    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setSizeMax(1073741824); //Limits the max file size (bytes)
        List<FileItem> items = null;
        try {
            items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String username = null;
        for(FileItem item : items){
            if(item.isFormField() && item.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase("username")){
                username = item.getString();
            } else if (!item.isFormField() && item.getSize() > 0) {
                try {
                    String filename = item.getName();

                    String dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss";
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
                    String date =  dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());

                    item.write(new File(fileRepository + username + "_" + date + "_" + filename));
                    resultStatus = "fileupload success";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultStatus;
}
```

But now I want to implement a service to download this file. Can I have some help on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? I have never used jax-rs, so im not sure if my code would COMPUTE!

```
@GET
@Produces("application/x-octet-stream")
public void downloadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    //fetch the file id from request object
    //get File using file id
    //dump file contents to response
}
```